# Генерация правил лексического анализатора на основе описания грамматики

Tags: синтаксический-анализ, грамматика, lex

Существуют ли готовые решения для генерации правил выводимых лексем на основе описания грамматики (если это в принципе возможно)?

Например, у меня есть файл описания синтаксиса языка N в БНФ. Могу ли я на основе этого файла сгенерировать правила выведения лексем для [flex](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flex_(%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80_%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%85_%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2))?